# How to draw multi-lines from multiple queries in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I am new to Kibana and need some help.

I can draw this line chart for a single query (java):

[image]

Now I would like to another line for another query (for example python) in the same chart. I am not so sure how to do that. Also "Markdown widget" is the way to add a legend?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible by adding the followings:

- X-Axis -> Split Lines -> Sub Aggregation -> Filters

In the filters, you can add multiple ones such as query:java, query:react and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as data is from same index we should be able to do it.

Any chart visualization edit  buckets configuration will have option to split line/chart using that you can do split lines.Here you can do split by attribute also if you want to go with date you can go with following steps in high level.

In Visualize, select Line Chart
For Y-Axis, select "Average", then select PRICE -- note, you can't plot the exact prices, it has to be some bucketing function
In X-Axis, select "Date Histogram", then select CHK_IN_DATE
Then select "Add Sub-Buckets", select "Split Lines", select "Terms", select "SOURCE_SITE_C"
You should get something similar to the screenshot below.

If your graph ends up being too messy with more lines than you expected, switch the order of steps 3 and 4 (or just use the arrow keys to switch the order of operations, see this blog80 for explanation)